# Origin of the term 'index of a subgroup'

Tags: group-theory, terminology

The index of a subgroup $H$ in a group $G$ is the number of distinct cosets of $H$ in $G$.

Why did someone decide to call this an 'index'?

Comment: Perhaps more suitable to https://hsm.stackexchange.com?